# no default web site on my new Windows Server 2019 iis to publish an ASP.NET hello world to

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I just created a new Windows Server 2019 on AWS EC2/
Next I used server mgr to install IIS.
Next, I tried to publish an ASP.NET .NET framework HELLO WORLD app,
but there's no web server to publish it to.

But when I open IIS Manager, I don't see Default Site (see image)...

[image]

In IIS Mgr I tried "Connect to a server", entered my admin account credentials, but got "Cound not connect... Unable to connect to the remote server"  (see below)

[image]

Comment: Maybe that's your very first time to use IIS Manager on a server, but experienced users should know you need to type "localhost" as "Server name:" (if you click Previous in the second screen shot), and then no credentials are needed. But how did you install IIS? If you only install IIS Management Console, then there would be nothing to manage.

Comment: That was no help.

Comment: If "no help" means you could not add "localhost", there is something wrong with your IIS installation. That would be hard to track down without accessing your machine. Either AWS gives you an improper image, or your steps to install in Server Manager missed certain things. Reveal more details, or use AWS's technical support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went to Server Manager > Roles > and installed more Web Server features,
restarted Windows and the problem went away.
IIS Manager now shows default Web, and I can now browse my HELLO WORLD web app from external Internet.